# Why did Sonny put piece of paper in the dead body's mouth?

Tags: time-travel, arq-2016

The "ARQ" movie explores the "stable time loop" theme. In the next to last iteration that we can see,

> Renton locks the two agents - Sonny and Cuz in his laboratory and drops the cyanide grenade through the air duct. The gas works slow enough to let Sonny do few more things: he kills Cuz and puts bodies together before committing suicide. At this stage Sonny is aware about the time loop, so he knows that his death might not be permanent.

Renton and Hannah are ready to run away with ARQ when Hannad notices a piece of paper in the mouth of one of the bodies - she takes it and finds that it has the codeword "SKY" written on it - code that would permanently destroy ARQ (and one that Sonny found during previous iteration).

> Unfortunately Hannah slips and dies electrocuted, forcing Renton to start another time loop.

What was the purpose of the piece of paper with the codeword? Was that just supposed to be a trap? If so, Sonny could easily make something better - i.e. connecting high voltage to the door or putting a tripwire of some sort. This "trap" worked only because Hannah was unfortunate enough to slip on blood, so it seems that this note might had a different purpose.